# How to construct an 'nested' object from timeseries data?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, object

I'm extracting time series data for cars using node.js and sql.

My query extracts the data in node.js, and it is available as *rawposdata*:

```
rawposdata =
[{carID: 1234,
   contact: 'john doe',
   TimeStamp: 10:00,
   Speed = 2.3},
{carID: 1234,
   contact: 'john doe',
   TimeStamp: 11:00,
   Speed = 2.4},
{carID: 1234,
   contact: 'john doe',
   TimeStamp: 12:00,
   Speed = 2.5}
{carID: 9876,
   contact: 'bob wills',
   TimeStamp: 10:00,
   Speed = 1.1},
{carID: 9876,
   contact: 'bob wills',
   TimeStamp: 11:05,
   Speed = 1.1},
{carID: 9876,
   contact: 'bob wills',
   TimeStamp: 12:00,
   Speed = 3.2},
]
```

I want to have it in the following form (array, obj, or whatever) so i can work with it:

```
mypositiondata = 
[carID: 1234,
 contact: 'john doe',
 timestamp: { ts0: 10:00,
              ts1: 11:00,
              ts2: 12:00},
 speed:     {s0: 2.3
             s1: 2.4
             s2: 2.5}],
[carID: 9876,
 contact: 'bob wills',
 timestamp: { ts0: 10:00,
              ts1: 11:05,
              ts2: 12:00},
 speed:     {s0: 1.1
             s1: 1.1
             s2: 3.2}]
```

I have looked through examples on the internet, read underscore docs. etc but it seems i'm not able to solve this. How can i structure this data?

I have somewhere between 50 and 150 cars to sort.
There are more both static (e.g.: carID) and dynamic (.e.g: speed) datapoints in the dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `reduce` to make an object and use `Object.values` to convert object to array.

```
let mypositiondata = Object.values(rawposdata.reduce((c, v) => {
  c[v.carID] = c[v.carID] || {carID: v.carID,contact: v.contact,timestamp: {},speed: {}}
  c[v.carID].timestamp["ts" + Object.keys(c[v.carID].timestamp).length] = v.TimeStamp;
  c[v.carID].speed["s" + Object.keys(c[v.carID].speed).length] = v.Speed;
  return c;
}, {}));
```

Here is a snippet:

```js
let rawposdata = [{carID: 1234,contact: 'john doe',TimeStamp: '10:00',Speed: 2.3},{carID: 1234,contact: 'john doe',TimeStamp: '11:00',Speed: 2.4},{carID: 1234,contact: 'john doe',TimeStamp: '12:00',Speed: 2.5},{carID: 9876,contact: 'bob wills',TimeStamp: '10:00',Speed: 1.1},{carID: 9876,contact: 'bob wills',TimeStamp: '11:05',Speed: 1.1},{carID: 9876,contact: 'bob wills',TimeStamp: '12:00',Speed: 3.2},];

let mypositiondata = Object.values(rawposdata.reduce((c, v) => {
  c[v.carID] = c[v.carID] || {carID: v.carID,contact: v.contact,timestamp: {},speed: {}}
  c[v.carID].timestamp["ts" + Object.keys(c[v.carID].timestamp).length] = v.TimeStamp;
  c[v.carID].speed["s" + Object.keys(c[v.carID].speed).length] = v.Speed;
  return c;
}, {}));

console.log(mypositiondata);
```

---

One option also is to use **array** instead of objects for timestamp and speed

```js
let rawposdata = [{carID: 1234,contact: 'john doe',TimeStamp: '10:00',Speed: 2.3},{carID: 1234,contact: 'john doe',TimeStamp: '11:00',Speed: 2.4},{carID: 1234,contact: 'john doe',TimeStamp: '12:00',Speed: 2.5},{carID: 9876,contact: 'bob wills',TimeStamp: '10:00',Speed: 1.1},{carID: 9876,contact: 'bob wills',TimeStamp: '11:05',Speed: 1.1},{carID: 9876,contact: 'bob wills',TimeStamp: '12:00',Speed: 3.2},];
let mypositiondata = Object.values(rawposdata.reduce((c,v)=>{
   c[ v.carID ] = c[ v.carID ] || {carID : v.carID, contact: v.contact, timestamp : [], speed : []}
   c[ v.carID ].timestamp.push( v.TimeStamp );
   c[ v.carID ].speed.push( v.Speed );
   return c;
},{}));
 
console.log( mypositiondata );
```

Without ES6

```js
var rawposdata = [{carID: 1234,contact: 'john doe',TimeStamp: '10:00',Speed: 2.3},{carID: 1234,contact: 'john doe',TimeStamp: '11:00',Speed: 2.4},{carID: 1234,contact: 'john doe',TimeStamp: '12:00',Speed: 2.5},{carID: 9876,contact: 'bob wills',TimeStamp: '10:00',Speed: 1.1},{carID: 9876,contact: 'bob wills',TimeStamp: '11:05',Speed: 1.1},{carID: 9876,contact: 'bob wills',TimeStamp: '12:00',Speed: 3.2},];

var temp = {};
var mypositiondata = [];

for (var k in rawposdata) {
  var v = rawposdata[k];
  if (typeof temp[v.carID] === "undefined") temp[v.carID] = {carID: v.carID, contact: v.contact, timestamp: [], speed: []};
  temp[v.carID].timestamp.push(v.TimeStamp);
  temp[v.carID].speed.push(v.Speed);
}

for (var k in temp) {
  var tSpeed = {};
  var tTStamp = {};

  for (var i in temp[k].speed) tSpeed["s" + i] = temp[k].speed[i];

  for (var i in temp[k].timestamp) tTStamp["ts" + i] = temp[k].timestamp[i];

  temp[k].speed = tSpeed;
  temp[k].timestamp = tTStamp;

  mypositiondata.push(temp[k]);
}

console.log(mypositiondata);
```

Comment: Hi, and thanks for answer. Sine this is my first time posting on StackOverflow: What is a snippet ? Is is supposed to be code that should run if copied to a application? Because, when i try to run both "snippets" i am told that Object.values "is not a function.

Comment: Just click on `Run code snippet` btn to check the result. And yes, you can copy the code and execute on a browser @otk

Comment: Very nice! However, still dont work in my environment. I use node v6.9.1.

Comment: As in top comment, i get the error "Object.values is not a funtion" when running it.. (Using VS2017, node.js console app)

Comment: Ohh maybe it is an IDE issue. But is functioning?

Comment: No, it wont execute. :)

Comment: Ohh.. Ill try to make a separate code without using ES6

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try to implement this now, and report back.